# Stop IE/Edge window resize to iframe dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

**The problem:**
When loading content into an iframe via an AJAX call, IE/Edge resizes the browser window to the width and height of the iframe instead of keeping the original dimensions. The iframe contains `<html><body>` tags and so on.

[image]

```html
<iframe id="main" name="main" 
frameborder="0" width="100%" height="600" 
style="height: 600px !important; width: 100% !important;" 
scrolling="no" src="/en/courseid2900">
  #document
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html></html>
</iframe>
```

*(before AJAX call in IE/Edge)*

[image]

```html
<iframe id="main" name="main" 
frameborder="0" width="100%" height=""
style="height: 696.796875px"
scrolling="no" src="/en/courseid2900">
  #document
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-US" class=" -webkit-">...</html>
</iframe>
```

*(after AJAX call in IE/Edge)*

So, is there a way **how to block the resizing of the window** to the iframe dimensions? Can it be done via jQuery or a HTML hack? Thanks.

Comment: I had no idea IE would do this - if I am understanding correctly - have you tried setting the iframes height directly? `<iframe height="600px"></iframe>`

Comment: @cidicles Added a before, after snippet in the question. But yes, I assume IE/Edge doesn't recognize multiple `<html>` tags or similar, so it thinks "I have to use dimensions of last `<html>` tag I find."

Comment: Do you have a jsbin or fiddle or something that shows this happening? Because setting the content of an iframe properly shouldn't do anything to the owning document in the slightest (you can't just "stick the code for a page" in an iframe element tag, you specify its src attribute an HTLM, or you need to do some manual dom manipulation on the JS side)

Answer (score 1):

Iframe elements [may not contain *any* content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-iframe-element) so the code you show in your post is 100% incorrect HTML. If you want content in an iframe, you either point it to a real URL using the `src` attribute, or you manually construct an iframe DOM node in JavaScript and then insert that into your document.

Any content that you put inside an iframe element as markup rather than through DOM manipulation through JS is by definition of the iframe element treated as *parent document* content. Doing what your post suggests, you've created a document with *two* `<html>` sections and it's not too surprising that browsers are going to do wildly incorrect things: you did something wildly incorrect =)

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a LMS system which generates this code (JoomlaLMS, Storyline 360), so I'll have to let them know it's structured incorrectly. I'll try to come up with a quick fix in the meantime.